# Nifi 1.5 Untrusted Proxy on cluster

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi

I've done my best to follow: https://pierrevillard.com/2016/11/29/apache-nifi-1-1-0-secured-cluster-setup/

I'm running nifi-1.5.0 and when I go to each of the pages I see an error like: Untrusted proxy CN=nifi-{1-3}.east.companyname.com, OU=NIFI.

I'm using ldap authentication, and just accepting the "invalid" certificate.

I've used an unrelated key-server to generate the keystore/truststore/certs as per the link above.

I also have the
`nifi.security.needClientAuth=true`
and
`nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=true`
set in the nifi.properties files on all of my nodes

my authorizers file includes entries for all of the nodes like:

`<property name="Node Identity 1">CN=nifi-1.east.companyname.com, OU=NIFI</property>
<property name="Node Identity 2">CN=nifi-2.east.companyname.com, OU=NIFI</property>
<property name="Node Identity 3">CN=nifi-3.east.companyname.com, OU=NIFI</property>`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've checked that the proxy identity DNs are lexicographically identical to the hostnames and certificate SPKI/SAN values (no extra/missing spaces, case-sensitive [I know RFC 5280 says DNs are not case-sensitive, but the NiFi comparison for authentication is])? Are you sure the truststore contains a valid entry for the CA certificate which signed the node certificates? Can you verify using OpenSSL `s_client` that the nodes are presenting the expected certificate? Can you check `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-user.log` for more details on the access attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend configuring your authorizer in `authorizers.xml` to use a `CompositeConfigurableUserGroupProvider` that has two user group providers:

1. `file-user-group-provider`: this will be used to store the identities (certificate DNs) of your cluster nodes
2. `ldap-user-group-provider`: for your end users, that will be proxied when the cluster is replicating requests

Configure both of these `UserGroupProviders`, then configure the `CompositeConfigurableUserGroupProvider` to use the file-user-group-provider as the "Configurable Provider" and the ldap-user-group-provider as "User Group Provider 1". Here is an example:

```
<authorizers>

    <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>file-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>

        <property name="Initial User Identity 1">CN=nifi-1.east.companyname.com, OU=NIFI</property>
        <property name="Initial User Identity 1">CN=nifi-2.east.companyname.com, OU=NIFI</property>
        <property name="Initial User Identity 1">CN=nifi-3.east.companyname.com, OU=NIFI</property>
    </userGroupProvider>

    <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>ldap-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.tenants.LdapUserGroupProvider</class>
        <!-- ... configure this to match the settings in login-identity-providers.xml ... -->
    </userGroupProvider>

    <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>composite-configurable-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.CompositeConfigurableUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Configurable User Group Provider">file-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="User Group Provider 1">ldap-user-group-provider</property>
    </userGroupProvider>

    <accessPolicyProvider>
        <identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
        <property name="User Group Provider">composite-configurable-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity"></property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>

        <property name="Node Identity 1">CN=nifi-1.east.companyname.com, OU=NIFI</property>
        <property name="Node Identity 2">CN=nifi-2.east.companyname.com, OU=NIFI</property>
        <property name="Node Identity 3">CN=nifi-3.east.companyname.com, OU=NIFI</property>
    </accessPolicyProvider>

    <authorizer>
        <identifier>managed-authorizer</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.StandardManagedAuthorizer</class>
        <property name="Access Policy Provider">file-access-policy-provider</property>
    </authorizer>

</authorizers>
```

Configure this on each node, **then remove `users.xml` and `authorizations.xml` and restart NiFi on each node**. (This is necessary to create the users.xml and authorizations.xml with your node identities setup to act as proxies, which will not happen if users.xml and authorizations.xml exist with data.) If done correctly, each node should allow the clustered nodes to authenticate using the client certificate (from their keystore.jks) and each node will be authorized to act as proxies, meaning that when an end-user is talking to one cluster, that interaction will be replicated to all nodes in the cluster, which is what you want.

You should be able to set `nifi.security.needClientAuth=false`. Certificate-based authentication will still work, it just won't be required (i.e., for the initial communication from an end-user to a node, LDAP credentials will be enough).

Hope this helps!

Reference: [NiFi Admin Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#authorizers-setup)

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked, now I'm on to a new problem: my cluster appears to be healthy, but my initial admin user isn't working... I've tried `CN=[myldap-login], OU=NIFI`, `CN=[myldap-login]`, and just my ldap-login in the `<property name="Initial Admin Identity"></property>` field,  but I either get an error or a **No applicable policies could be found. Contact the system administrator.** error... what format should my initial admin identity be in?

Comment: Oddly, when I set `<property name="Initial Admin Identity"></property>` and `<property name="Initial User Identity 4"></property>` to be my `[ldap-username]` the error changes to `javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

Comment: You would want to set the Initial Admin Identity to whatever user identity will match what is configured in your ldap-user-group-provider in authorizers.xml (which should also match how your ldap-provider in login-identity-provider.xml is configured).

Comment: Thanks! now I'm seeing WARN [Replicate Request Thread-6] o.a.n.c.c.h.r.ThreadPoolRequestReplicator Failed to replicate request GET /nifi-api/flow/current-user to nifi-2.east.companyname.com:9443 due to javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-03-19 23:26:21,966 WARN [Replicate Request Thread-6] o.a.n.c.c.h.r.ThreadPoolRequestReplicator
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) 
.... on node-2 no matter what node I hit.

Comment: The stack trace is much, much longer, but I can't post the whole thing in here.

Comment: Looks like I needed to change the format of my /etc/hosts file on each of my nodes to the format: 
`[internal-ip] [fqdn] [hostname]`  
`127.0.0.1 localhost`  
. . .


there should be line breaks after each entry, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Is there anything in the logs on the node that it is trying to connect to?

Comment: no, the problem turned out to be the there was no SNI for 127.0.0.1/localhost. So, when the call was "replicated" locally, the cert validation failed in the java layer.